# How to setup Tailwind for a new Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli, tailwind-css

I want to create a new Angular project using Tailwind CSS. My current CLI version is 10.1.1. Things I have done so far:

- Create a new app using `ng new my-app`
- Use Angular routing => yes
- Use SCSS as the stylesheet
- In the root directory of the project run `npm i tailwindcss postcss-import postcss-loader postcss-scss @angular-builders/custom-webpack -D`
- In the src folder there is a **styles.scss** file, modify it to

.

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

- In the root directory of the project run `npx tailwind init`
- In the root directory of the project create a new file **webpack.config.js** with the following content

.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          ident: "postcss",
          syntax: "postcss-scss",
          plugins: () => [
            require("postcss-import"),
            require("tailwindcss"),
            require("autoprefixer"),
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

- In the root directory there is a **Angular.json** file

  - Search for the key projects => my-app => architect => build

    - Change the builder to `"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",`
    - Add to the options

.

```
"customWebpackConfig": {
    "path": "./webpack.config.js"
},
```

- Search for the key projects => my-app => architect => serve

  - Change the builder to `"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",`
  - Add to the options

.

```
"customWebpackConfig": {
    "path": "./webpack.config.js"
},
```

- Run the app with `ng serve` from the app's root directory

I'm getting this error

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??postcss!./src/styles.scss)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been
> initialized using an options object that does not match the API
> schema.
>
> - options has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:    object { postcssOptions?, execute?, sourceMap? }
>   at validate (/.../my-app/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:98:11)
>   at Object.loader (/.../my-app/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:43:28)
>
> ERROR in Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js): ValidationError: Invalid
> options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options
> object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - same text as above

How can I setup Tailwind correctly?

Comment: Maybe this is easier: https://trungk18.com/experience/configure-tailwind-css-with-angular/

Comment: thanks but I would like to avoid installing a tool to use another tool

Comment: I can reproduce that on my machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imports are 'tailwindcss', not 'tailwind':

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Answer (score 6):

I have found the answer after banging my head everywhere today, change your webpack.config.js to,

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            ident: "postcss",
            syntax: "postcss-scss",
            plugins: [
              require("postcss-import"),
              require("tailwindcss"),
              require("autoprefixer"),
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

There is small change, plugins now take array instead of function.
Thanks in advance .

---

If anyone is still running into issue, checkout this blog I've written on Angular 10 + Tailwind CSS

https://fullyunderstood.com/get-started-with-angular-tailwind-css/

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply! That solved one error, but there is still one left. I will post it in the next comment

Comment: `ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--13-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-4!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--17!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Failed to find 'tailwind/base'
  in [
    /.../my-app/src
  ]
    at /.../my-app/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13`

Comment: but as I mentioned in the question I'm importing `tailwind/base` in the styles.scss file

Comment: I also tested it on another fresh installed machine, I get the same error

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. It resolved my issue. But the CSS is not working on the website.

Comment: while I can reproduce the errors your solution unforunately only fixes one error, as the OP already mentioned

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get Angular 10 + Angular Material to work with Tailwind CSS using configuration highlighted in this diff - [Tailwind CSS support in Angular 10, with Angular Material](https://gist.github.com/kctang/7cd64e8a3f519a65e18351856f67a554).

Some key points besides what has already been highlighted in the question/answers:

- Need to explicitly install postcss (8.x). Somehow default pulls (7.x) causing `Error: true is not a PostCSS plugin`.
- Config in webpack.config.js depends on postcss-loader version 4.x.
- If you are using Angular Material, you will get `Error: Failed to find '~@angular/material/theming'`. To resolve this, I limit the scss files that will be processed by postcss by separating the scss file (i.e. `test: /tailwind\.scss$/` in webpack.config.js).

So far, looks like it is working.

Comment: Assuming the project is scss – for me using postcss v8.x worked, i didn't need the other steps.

Comment: I was searching for a solution for hours you third step just save me thanks !

Answer (score -2):

Installing TailwindCSS (Angular version

***If your Angular version is greater than or equal to 11.2.0, you can skip this section***

The easiest way to use TailwindCSS in your Angular app with version less than 11.2.0 in my personal opinion is by using the [@ngneat/tailwind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/tailwind) npm package. I had a great experience with it (plug and play).

1. First step is to run the following schematic in your Angular project: `ng add @ngneat/tailwind`
2. When asked if you want to enable dark mode select `class`
3. When asked if you would you like to use Tailwind directives & functions in component styles? select `Yes`
4. When asked what TailwindCSS plugins you want to enable, select `forms` and `typography` or all of them. That's up to you.

[image: angular tailwind]

There's 4 parts we need to focus on after we have installed TailwindCSS in our Angular app.

-A new file created `tailwind.config.js` it should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/devpato/ba3507c91396fe852ffde9c0c93bf437)

-A new file created `webpack.config.js` it should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/devpato/0c39042d10993e24c64540696a19bad6)

-The new `dark` class added to your `index.html` body element

```html
<body class="dark">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

-Some imports added to your `styles.scss` file

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

**Note: To turn on purge in your production build follow this tiny tweet**

**OPTIONAL**

Take a look to [this](https://youtu.be/XFxuKUBUqao) amazing video created by my friend Beeman. It shows you how use TailwindCSS in Angular in 3 MINUTES!

**If you want to learn how to do it in Angular 11.2.0**

https://dev.to/angular/setup-tailwindcss-in-angular-the-easy-way-1i5l

Comment: Given that the dev.to article was authored by ["Pato"](https://dev.to/devpato), who says they are "Google Developer Expert on Angular and Web Technologies" and this answer's author profile (Patricio) says they are "Google Developer Expert on Angular and Web Technologies", I'm inclined to believe it's one and the same person, and just needs to disclose that fact more directly.