# How to add tailwindcss on the angular library?

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I just want to ask how to add tailwindcss framework on the angular library, am I going to install it inside the library (mli-questionnaire) or on the root folder/workspace?

```
>dist
>node_modules
>projects
   >mli-questionnaire
   >mli-questionnaire-test
.editorconfig
.gitignore
angular.json
package.json
package-lock.json
README.md
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup Tailwind for a new Angular project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858991/how-to-setup-tailwind-for-a-new-angular-project)

Comment: Did you find the answer? Can you please update post if there is an answer?

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858991/how-to-setup-tailwind-for-a-new-angular-project